# Where did the estimation rule of thumb originate that time spent will be one-third in each of the following: design, implementation, and testing?

Tags: project-management, estimation

I'm looking for a reference to the following.  I commonly hear that one-third of a projects time will be spent in design, one-third in implementation, and one-third in testing.  The three phases of development seems to be derived from the waterfall model.  But, where did the time division originate (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)?  Is there a paper or book that this is from?

Comment: [Citation needed]

Comment: This was [discussed on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158158/why-was-this-closed) prior to being migrated here. The way I read the question it's about finding the source of an oft quoted rule of thumb (I've heard the "1/3 rule" quite a few times myself), and _not_ about discussing its merits - we have a [ton of questions about estimation in general](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation?sort=votes&pagesize=50) were answers discussing the merits of various estimation techniques would be more appropriate.

Comment: What makes you think this is a standard rule of thumb? Can you site a reference?

Comment: @BryanOakley It probably isn't a standard rule of thumb, but I've heard it (or slight variations of) constantly since my early days in the field, a little bit over a decade ago. I'm certain I also read it somewhere online, but I can't remember where (and it probably was some blog or something like that).

Comment: Bryan Oakley, you are asking my question.  I am asking for a reference when I ask, "Is there a paper or a book that this is from?"  What person originated this rule of thumb? Brooks (Mythical Man Month), Yourdon, etc.?

Answer (score 7):

The rule of thumb you're describing sounds extremely similar to Brooks' rule of thumb, as presented in [the Mythical Man-Month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month):

> For some years I have been successfully using the following
>   rule of thumb for scheduling a software task:
>
> 1/3 planning
>   1/6 coding
>   1/4 component test and early system test
>   1/4 system test, all components in hand.
>
> This differs from conventional scheduling in several important ways:
>
> 1. The fraction devoted to planning is larger than normal. Even so, it is barely enough to produce a detailed and solid specification, and not enough to include research or exploration of totally new techniques.
> 2. The half of the schedule devoted to debugging of completed code is much larger than normal.
> 3. The part that is easy to estimate, i.e., coding, is given only one-sixth of the schedule.

I don't know where exactly your rule of thumb comes from, but it certainly looks like a derivative of Brooks' rule of thumb.